# Singleton not persisting across viewcontrollers/spritekit scene

Tags: ios, singleton, sprite-kit

This is a SpriteKit game.

I am using a singleton to store a single 'Show' object to be accessible throughout the game. The 'Show' class has an NSString property 'showTitle'.

In ViewController1, I set the 'Show' property of the singleton. To test.. I then printed out a string property of 'Show' (showTitle) from the singleton and it prints the string correctly.

After segueing to ViewController2, I again print out the same string property of 'Show' (showTitle) from the singleton and it again prints the string correctly.

THEN, the spritekit scene is initialized from ViewController2. I attempt to print the same string property
 of 'Show' from the singleton, and it prints null instead of the string. I went further and segued to ViewController3, tried to print the showTitle from the singleton..... NULL.

Why am I able to access the 'Show' property of the singleton in ViewControllers 1 & 2, but not from within the sprite kit scene or ViewController3. Where am I going wrong?

ShowSingleton.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Show.h"

@interface ShowSingleton : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) Show* currentShow;

+(ShowSingleton *)singleton;

@end
```

ShowSingleton.m

```
#import "ShowSingleton.h"

@implementation ShowSingleton

@synthesize currentShow;

+(ShowSingleton *)singleton {
    static dispatch_once_t pred;
    static ShowSingleton *shared = nil;

    dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
        shared = [[ShowSingleton alloc] init];
    });

    return shared; }

@end
```

ViewController1:

```
- (IBAction)openShow:(UIButton*)sender
    {
        //showsarray is an array of 'Show' objects retrieved through core data in another class
        [ShowSingleton singleton].currentShow = [showsarray objectAtIndex:sender.tag];

        NSLog(@"Opened show: %@", [ShowSingleton singleton].currentShow.showTitle);
        //The above line correctly prints the selected showTitle from the singleton
}
```

After openShow: completes, a segue opens ViewController2. ViewController2 initializes the SpriteKit scene.

ViewController2:

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];

    SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
    if (!skView.scene)
    {
        skView.showsFPS = YES;
        skView.showsNodeCount = YES;
        SKScene * scene = [iMarchMyScene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
        scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
        [skView presentScene:scene];
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    //The following line correctly prints the showTitle from ViewController2
    NSLog(@"processing show: %@", [ShowSingleton singleton].currentShow.showTitle);
}
```

myScene.m:

```
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size
{
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size])
    {
        if ([ShowSingleton singleton].currentShow)
        {
            //This always gets called, which tells me the object exists, but null is printed for showTitle
             NSLog(@"show title from scene: %@", [ShowSingleton singleton].currentShow.showTitle);
        }
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using [this](https://github.com/NYTimes/objective-c-style-guide#singletons) singleton implementation:

```
// ShowSingleton.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Show.h"

@interface ShowSingleton : NSObject

+ (instancetype)singleton;

@end

// ShowSingleton.m

#import "ShowSingleton.h"

@implementation ShowSingleton

+ (instancetype)singleton {
   static id sharedInstance = nil;

   static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
   dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
      sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
   });

   return sharedInstance;
}

@end
```

Comment: if you *must* roll your own singleton, (and I'd really apply some skepticism to that premise first) then Andrey is right, and to boot he's showing you how to use instancetype as opposed to id, which is absolutely beautiful in this context for reasons which don't fit in my comment character limit...

Comment: I know singletons are generally a no no. It was the first thing I thought of. Do any of you have a better recommendation for what I'm doing? 'Show' is a CoreData object. Once the user selects their object from a list, other view controllers and scene's will update the UI, variables, etc. based on that one CoreData object. I thought a singleton was a good place to store the object for global use. What's a better way of doing it? Keep in mind that any of the view controllers can make changes to the object and persist it in the store. The managedObjectContext is in the appDelegate.

Answer (score 1):

`ShowSingleton *shared` is scoped to the method, not the class.

Try declaring it as a class property of your AppDelegate, and then override the getter with something like this:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) Show *currentShow;
```

and then override the getter as:

```
+(Show*)currentShow
{
    static id _currentShow = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        currentShow = [showsarray objectAtIndex:sender.tag]; //probably not this, not sure where in your app flow this info is ready...
    });
    return _currentShow;
}
```

Now you can leverage the proper singleton UIApplicationDelegate that Apple provided, and end up with an unchanging instance of `Show` that is accessible anywhere in your app by calling `(YourApplicationClass*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] currentShow]`

Keep in mind that dispatch_once is tied to the App Lifecycle. It will be purged when and only when the app terminates, which may be while your app is in the background.

Singleton's are fiddly to implement correctly, and even more difficult to know when their use is actually warranted, so you may want to take a look at `NSUserDefaults` to see if it has something you could bend to your purposes instead.